# What alternatives are there to onLocationChanged()?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I'm using Android and Google Maps at API level 10, and I get latitude and longitude by telnet.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lng = location.getLongitude();
    //...
}
```

But the user should move first.  Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to onLocationChanged(Location location) is using a location manager and broadcast receiver to get the user's location information. Refer to the docs to read all about the [Location Manager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). With the location manager class you will be able to set an interval in which you want to probe the user's location even when they haven't moved. You will have:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            List<String> knownProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();

            if(locationManager != null && pendingIntent != null && knownProviders.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINUTE_INTERVAL*5, 0, pendingIntent);
            }

            if(locationManager != null && pendingIntent != null && knownProviders.contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MINUTE_INTERVAL*5, 0, pendingIntent);
            }
```

In the LocationReceiver class (Broadcast Receiver) you will have an onRecieve() method in which you can use:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        location = (Location) bundle.get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
```

You can use that location object for many things, refer to the  [Android Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) docs.

Comment: If this resolved your issue, then you should mark the answer as accepted. The tick symbol on left under the vote count.